# "import _pjsua" Error. DLL load failed: the specific module could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I encountered the following error while executing a python file on Jetbrains Pycharm IDE.

```
from pjsua import *
import _pjsua
Error. DLL load failed: the specific module could not be found
```

Initially, I thought this error is related to python installation. So, I re-installed python but i couldn't remove the error.
I ran the code in some other system and the code worked fine.
I think the problem is due to some dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the problem was due to Microsoft Re-distributables. I installed all the versions from 2005 to 2017 (both x86 and x64) and restarted my system.
This resolved my problem.